# How do aggregate operations work on Java streams?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, java-stream

In the following excerpt from [the Java tutorials in aggregate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect), we map the names of the people to their sexes.

```
Map<Person.Sex, List<String>> namesByGender =
roster
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getGender,                      
            Collectors.mapping(
                Person::getName,
                Collectors.toList())));
```

I understand that the collect operation:
1) Groups each Person in the stream by the result of getGender.
2) Maps each Person to the result of getName.
3) Forms a list from the results and.
4) Generates a Map whose keys are the Persons' genders and whose data values are the Persons' names.

My questions are:
1) In what order do the Collectors act?
2) What are the intermittent types between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Collectors do not “act”, hence do not act in an order. It’s not like one Collector processes all data before passing it to another using an intermittent type.

You are *composing* a single Collector with these factories, which will do the entire work at once when being passed to `Stream.collect`.

As the [documentation of the `Collector` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collector.html) explains:

> A Collector is specified by four functions that work together to accumulate entries into a mutable result container, and optionally perform a final transform on the result. They are:
>
> - creation of a new result container (supplier())
> - incorporating a new data element into a result container (accumulator())
> - combining two result containers into one (combiner())
> - performing an optional final transform on the container (finisher())

So the `toList()` collector can be implemented as simple as `ArrayList::new` as supplier, `List::add` as accumulator and `List::addAll` as combiner, not needing a custom finisher, which is how it is indeed implemented in the reference implementation, but that’s an implementation detail, other implementations are allowed.

Then, [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is composing a new collector using the specified *downstream* collector and decorating it’s accumulator function by applying the specified *mapper* function first and passing its result to the original accumulator function. The result is again a collector consisting of four functions. During the collect operation, the *mapper* function will be applied for each element right before adding to the list.

Finally, [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) will do a much more complex composition. The supplier will create a new map, typically `HashMap`. The accumulator will evaluate your grouping function and store the result into the map, using an operation like `Map.computeIfAbsent` which will evaluate the *downstream* collector’s supplier if the key is new, followed by applying the *downstream* collector’s accumulator function, which is the composed function in your scenario. The combiner function settles on `Map.merge` using either map’s value if only one contains a key or using the *downstream*’s combiner if a key is present in both maps.

So the processing of a composed collector consists of an interleaved processing of the specified functions rather than processing one collector after the other. In other words, for a sequential execution, the operation will be equivalent to

```
Map<Person.Sex, List<String>> namesByGender = new HashMap<>();
for(Person p: roster)
    namesByGender.computeIfAbsent(p.getGender(), k -> new ArrayList()).add(p.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look at `groupingBy's` sources we'll see following:

```
Supplier<A> downstreamSupplier = downstream.supplier();
        BiConsumer<A, ? super T> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
        BiConsumer<Map<K, A>, T> accumulator = (m, t) -> {
            K key = Objects.requireNonNull(classifier.apply(t), "element cannot be mapped to a null key");
            A container = m.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> downstreamSupplier.get());
            downstreamAccumulator.accept(container, t);
        };
```

First. Computes key calling `Person::getGender`.

Second. If key doesn't exist creates new downstream container `ArrayList::new`

Third. Add element returns from `Person::getName` to container `List::add`

`ArrayList::new` and `List::add` we can find as parameters of `CollectorImpl` constructor if we look at `Collectors.toList` method