# split a list stream into a map does need a custom Collector?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

am new to Stream but not so much... this is my problem:

I have a list that am reading from pc where I have users with some kind of *rights* over an exe file... the list I got as a String looks like

```
List<String> xyzList = new ArrayList<>();
xyzList.add("USER1.READ");
xyzList.add("USER1.WRITE");
xyzList.add("USER1.EXECUTE");
xyzList.add("USER1.DELETE");
xyzList.add("USER2.READ");
xyzList.add("USER3.READ");
xyzList.add("USER2.EXECUTE");
```

I would like to have a `Map<String, String>` like

```
{USER1 = READ-WRITE-EXECUTE-DELETE, USER2 = READ-WRITE, USER3 = READ}
```

but my code is producing:

```
{USER1=USER1.READ-USER1.WRITE-USER1.EXECUTE-USER1.DELETE,  USER2=USER2.READ-USER2.EXECUTE, USER3=USER3.READ}
```

I know i can edit the set of values if i decide to keep working with that result but am looking a more elegant way of get that in a only one stream instruction and I have the feeling I will need a custom collector for that...

my try so far..

```
Map<String, String> result = xyzList
        .stream()
        .collect(
             Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.split("\\.")[0],  
             Collectors.joining("-", "", "")
         ));

System.out.println(result);
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Strip the first part in a `mapping` `Collector`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this (you were really close btw):

```
xyzList.stream()
       .map(x -> x.split("\\."))
       .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0],
            Collectors.mapping(
                         arr -> arr[1], 
                         Collectors.joining("-"))))
```

Comment: yes... it is exactly what a need... if you could elaborate a bit about the Collectors.mapping would be great.. thankyou!!

Comment: @FlascheLeer i dont know what to say. .. its basically mapping ( apply a Function) to the elements before collecting them

Comment: @FlascheLeer actually just today a great explanation on these things here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125135/how-to-aggregate-operations-work-on-java-streams/47158659#47158659